# Exportar array dentro de uma tabela?

Tags: php, html, funções

Preciso exportar dados de um array dentro de uma tabela html, a função está funcionando mas não sei como exportar com while dentro de uma tabela, fiz uma analogia com o código a baixo.

```
function imprimir_Tbl($Id, $Nome){
$array = array();

for($i=0; $i<= $Id; $i++){
    $array["id"][] = $i + 1;
    $array["nome"][] = $Nome.' '.($i + 1);
}
return $array;}
```

Usando var_dump os dados são impressos corretamente, o resultado esperado é o seguinte

```
<table border="0">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Nome</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Nome 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Nome 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Nome 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>Nome 4</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Voce quer usar aquela função para preencher a tabela?Ou a função é só para preencher o array?

Comment: @LocalHost eu tenho uma função que faz diversos cálculos e no final ela devolve um array com o resultado e o resultado eu preciso que seja apresentado em uma tabela onde $array["id"][0] coincida com a segunda coluna $array["nome"][0], espero ter sanado a dúvida, e obrigado.

Comment: Ah sim, compreendi. Porque do jeito que colocou dá a entender que o seu array não serviu para nada, por simplesmente ser ma forma de você imprimir a tabela

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar o `foreach` para listar os resultados no HTML.

Na função PHP você pode juntar o ID com o Nome em um mesmo Array, por utilizar a variável `$i` do `for`.

### PHP

```
<?php

function imprimir_Tbl($Id, $Nome){
    $array = array();

    for($i = 0; $i <= $Id; $i++){
        $array[$i]["id"]    = $i + 1;
        $array[$i]["nome"]  = $Nome.' '.($i + 1);
    }
    return $array;

}

$array = imprimir_Tbl(10, 'Nome');
```

### HTML

```
<table border="0">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Nome</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

<?php
   foreach($array as $key => $value){
?> 

<tr>
   <td><?=$value['id']?></td>
   <td><?=$value['nome']?></td>
</tr>

<?php   
   }
?>

</tbody>
```

Comment: muito obrigado pela força, o foreach resolveu o problema, fiz uma alteração para inserir os dados no Bd.